# Docker for Azure

Tags: azure, docker

I have a docker image which is to be moved to Azure but I am confused with options as of now Azure has provided forllowing option
1: Docker VM extension(which require TLS certs)
2: Docker Container instance(still in preview)
3. Docker Azure Driver(looks like an easy to configure docker over VM)

Which option should I use and is there is any more easy to use option for docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a docker image which is to be moved to Azure

If you just want to do some test with Azure docker, as Adam said, we can use Docker Azure driver or docker machine, create an Azure VM and install docker on it. You can follow Adam's links to do that. We can use VM's public IP address to access the docker, works like `bridge`.

> Docker Container instance(still in preview)

You are right, for now, Azure container service(**AKS**) still in preview, AKS is a managed kubernetes in Azure.

We can use Azure container service(**unmanaged,ACS**) to create [k8s cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-tutorial-kubernetes-deploy-cluster) or [swarm or DC/OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-deployment). In the cluster, we can expose the service to internet with `Azure Load Balancer`.

So, if you just want to test docker with Azure, maybe we should use Docker machine or Docker Azure Driver. (low cost)

If you want to create a docker for production, maybe we should use ACS cluster to avoid single point of failure.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Apologies, for the delay I was not checking this thread. Yes this definitely placed few things in perspective.

Answer (score 0):

The Docker Azure driver and docker-machine options seem to be straight forward for your case; here’s a step by step guide on how to get started with both: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/docker-machine , and the Docker Azure driver documentation can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/azure/  .

-Adam